# SSRS - Reusing temp table in multiple datasets

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report on SSRS which has 14 subreports. All of these subreports read from the same stored procedure but present the data in different ways (because of different calculations). The way I have the SP written is as follows:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#blabla') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN DROP TABLE #blabla END
SELECT a,b,c,d,e
INTO #blabla
WHERE a='bla'

IF @type = 1 --report 1
   BEGIN
      SELECT ....
   END
IF @type = 2 --report 2
   BEGIN
      SELECT .....
   END
```

And so on for each report.

I create 3 temporary tables at the beginning of the stored procedure which are the ones that feed the data to be converted. The problem is that for each sub-report, the tables keep recreating themselves, which causes the report to take a long time to get created. Is there any workaround available that may re-use the tables created at the start of the stored procedure?

Comment: How often does the data change? If this is done with a nightly batch, perhaps you could make regular tables instead of temp tables ans put the data there in the night batch? Then have the SP's look in those tables instead of creating temps.

Comment: This is not done as an ETL process, the temp tables are just extracts from permanent tables (which are medical claims, so there are millions and millions of rows). The temps are a way to minimize the reads done into the permanent tables. They can't be permanent because the report has date parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using separate subreports, the queries for each of them won't use the same transaction where the temp tables are. SQL Server drops the tables when the connection for the query is lost.

You could try combining all your subreports into one. They would allow you to use the #TEMP tables for each query if you check the `Use Single Transaction` box in the **Datasource**.

Another was would be to use Global Temp Tables - **##TEMP**. Global Temp tables do not get dropped automatically and would be able to be used by other subreports.

Comment: I tried combining all subreports into one and checking that box, but it still took too long. I've also thought about using Global Temp Tables but wouldn't that create conflicts if some other person opened the report at the same time?

Comment: I have shared global temp files in SSRS and have not had issues doing so.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another table (control table) that contains one row which contains two columns - the start and end dates of the temp table. When each report starts it should check the current date against the dates in the control table. If the dates are not current rebuild the temp tables otherwise just continue processing. If you are creating temp tables that will be shared this way you probably don't want to create temp tables just regular tables.

Another approach is to run a SQL Server job that rebuilds the work table every night at midnight.

By the way you can create indexes on temporary tables and you should seriously consider adding a clustered index to the temp table. You may find that you have much faster results running against such a table even if its a 'small' table.