# SSRS - How to use ##Temptable for data set parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I have an SSRS report the has cascading parameters, but the report is experiencing latency issue in loading cascading parameter.  Is there a method to use global temptable '##' for each cascading parameters i have.

1. Created a Global Parameters ##Parameters

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##Parameters  SELECT  * INTO  ##Parameters  FROM            Process.func_ClientListRollUp_RptGroup(@StartDate, @EndDate, 'CSA,BAOB,CAOS,NONE', 'PG')
2. Called a parameter from ##Parameters

SELECT DISTINCT PGType FROM ##Parameters WHERE LOB IN (@LOB) ORDER BY PGType

3. Received an Error upon report rendering

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'PGType'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Invalid object name '##Parameters'.

Comment: In theory you could use global temp tables but if two users ran the report at the same time you could get unexpected results. I would concentrate on getting the function more efficient if I was you. I'm not sure what the data looks like or how much there is but you might want to consider building help tables that summarise some of the data so that the function has less work to do. Hard to tell without more details though.

Comment: I have other reports that utlizes sql stored procedure and calling the parameter from the stored procedure.

Comment: Use local # temp tables, not global. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184762/ssrs-reusing-temp-table-in-multiple-datasets

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSRS - Reusing temp table in multiple datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184762/ssrs-reusing-temp-table-in-multiple-datasets)